# Competitive Programming : Generating test cases and validating the program correctness

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have been doing sport programming for a while and still improving day by day. But one thing I have always wondered is that it would be really nice if I could automate the test-case generation process and cross-validation of my program. Definitely it would be a brute force approach as some test cases would be algorithm specific.

Doing a google search gives me a nice link on Quora : [How do programming contest problem setters make test cases ?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-programming-contest-problem-setters-make-test-cases) and the popular [testlib](https://github.com/MikeMirzayanov/testlib) used by problem setters.

But isn't this a chicken-egg problem?

Assume I generated 1 million input test cases, but what would I check them against? How will I generate the outputs? Because I am still in the process of validating the program... If my script generates the correct outputs as well, then whats the point of writing the program in the first place. I can submit the script itself. Also, its not possible to write 1 million outputs for generated test cases manually. Can anyone please clarify this confusion.

I hope i have clarified the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to generate the answer by a slow but obviously correct solution (like an exhaustive search). It can't be used as a main solution as it's too slow for large test cases, but you can check the output of your fast (but possibly incorrect) program using it.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the answer to the question.... Obviously, I know that the test script cannot be used as the main solution. It serves an entirely different purpose, behaving differently. 

The question was - HOW? How do one automatically generates the outputs as well?

Comment: @InsaneCoder I'm not talking about the generator script. I'm talking about another slower solution which is simpler than the main one (it's a third file which has nothing to do with your original solution and the script you use for test case generation).

Answer (score 1):

Well the thing is it is not as broad as you think it to be. Test generation in competitive programming is guided by the algorithm of the problem and it's correctness proof.

---

So when you are thinking that there are million of test cases if you analyze the different situations the program can be then you will likely to get all the test cases. Maybe in certain algorithm you are some times processing the even index elements or the odd index elements of an array. Now what you will do? Divide it in 2 cases even or odd. Consider the smallest case for even ones . Same for odd ones. This way you are basically visiting all the control flow path of the program.

---

In competitive programming as we first determine the algorithm then we decide on a proper input sizes and then all this test cases and validations, it is often easy to think the corner points. Test case for 1000000 elements or when input is 0 or 1 ...test cases like this.

---

Another is most of the time we write a brute force solution much more slower than the original one. Now what we do? we just generate random medium size test cases and then run it again the slow program and we can check with our checker solution etc.

---

correctness is guided by some mathematical proof also.(Heuristics, Induction, Box principle, Number Theory etc ) That way we are sure about the correctness of the solution.

Comment: But I have seen some people submitting test cases for some problems, where the inputs for a single test case are so huge, to process manually. Going through a single test case and determining the correct output requires more than half hour. Forget generating multiple test cases.

Need example : https://www.udebug.com/UVa/162

Comment: @InsaneCoder  Hey..yes sometimes large randomly generated cases are used and they are checked using a valid program running in correct time complexity. (Then only the correctness of our checker solution is something we have).

Comment: So does that mean that we always write 2 programs - one with low time complexity and the other brute force? If yes, then we need to test brute force method also for its correctness and with the same process... Wouldn't it will be an endless chain?

Comment: @InsaneCoder.: Not a rule to write two..and not always .. Most of the time it is heuristics but yes teh coders I know who create those problems always write a checker along with the solution code.

Comment: Thanks. But then, what do the participants normally do if it comes to automated testing. My scenario is : sometimes I am not able to find the failing test case. So I want to write some `generator.cpp` to feed random test cases to my incorrect program, in order to find the failing test cases. But I also need to have the expected outputs to compare to. The only point is that is there a way to also obtain the expected outputs automatically by `generator.cpp` ?

Comment: Slower solution might work here and sometimes reasning...like this..Its really a heauristic stage..

Comment: Sorry I didn't get

Comment: @InsaneCoder.: To verify either you have to have a slow solution but correct one which will likely to give correct answer. Or In some cases a checker program (like ..for some questions like this ...Write a permuation of these n numbers so that it follows this rule...) That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue earlier this year and saw some of my colleagues also figuring out a way to deal with this. Because there are sometimes when I just couldn’t think any more test cases and that’s when I decided to make a test case generator tool of my own, It’s free and open-source so anyone can use it.

You can easily generate a lot of test cases using this tool and validate the result using the output given from the correct but slower approach(in terms of time complexity and space complexity). You can either run them parallelly and check for outputs or write a simple script to compare the output of both programs (the slower but correct one and the better but unsure one) to validate.

I believe good coders won’t be needing it anyway, but for the middle level (div2, div3) coders and newbies, it can prove to be a lot helpful.
You can access it from GitHub : [Test Case generator](https://github.com/Tanmay-901/test-case-generatorz).

[image]

Both python source code and .exe files are present there with instructions,

- If you want to make some changes of your own you can work with the python file.
- If you just directly want it to generate some test cases you should prefer the .exe file(inside the zip).
  It’ll help a lot if you’re beginning your Competitive programming journey.

Also, any suggestions or improvements are always welcome. Additionally you can also contribute to this project by adding some feature that you think the project is lacking or by adding some new test case formats by yourselves or making by request for the same.